# Reshape data frame for LSTM sequence classification to group on UserID

Tags: pandas-groupby, lstm, reshape

I am trying to reshape my data frame for sequence classification using an LSTM.
The challenge is to first group the records by UserID into a single sample, then transform the results into an array of shape (nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim). Not sure how to manpulate the dataframe to achieve the desired format for LSTM. I need to pad the sequences with zeros in case the lengths differ for each UserID.

The data frame looks like the below.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJhvw.png)

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

d=dict(
    {
        "UserID":['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 
        "Date":['01/03/2022','03/03/2022','09/03/2022','17/03/2022','20/03/2022','29/03/2022','29/03/2022','31/03/2022'],
        "Feature1":[5,25,21,20,27,25,11,15],
        "Feature2":[26,18,14,41,8,9,7,38],
        "Feature3":[44,5,15,12,20,47,8,21],
        "Target":[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,]
    }
)
```

Anyone can help please?

Comment: Can you please use you example to show how the result is supposed to look like?

Comment: Hi @Markus, as per Keras documentation LSTMs expect the input to be in the form (nb_samples, timesteps, input_dim), so that is why need some assistance on how best to address this.